# How do collinear points on a matrix affect its rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrix

\begin{matrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}

what effect does $({x_1},{y_1})$,$({x_2},{y_2})$,$({x_3},{y_3})$ being collinear have on the rank of the above matrix ?

Comment: I think the OP is talking of *points*, not vectors. Any two points in euclidean space are always collinear, but three need not...

Comment: @DonAntonio Right. That was a very poor comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(x_i\,,\,y_i)\;,\,\,i=1,2,3\;,\;\;\text{are collinear}\;\;\iff \frac{y_3-y_2}{x_3-x_2}=\frac{y_3-y_1}{x_3-x_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\iff$$

$$\iff (x_2-x_1)(y_3-y_2)=(y_2-y_1)(x_3-x_2)\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(x_3-x_1)(y_2-y_1)=(x_2-x_1)(y_3-y_1)\\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(x_3-x_2)(y_2-y_1)=(x_2-x_1)(y_3-y_2)$$

If one of the denominators vanishes (and thus all of them), then $\,x_1=x_2=x_3\,$ , and we have two columns linearly dependent and the determinant in then zero, otherwise and using the above equality:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}=x_1(y_2-y_3)+x_2(y_3-y_1)+x_3(y_1-y_2)=$$

$$=(x_3-x_2)(y_2-y_1)+x_2\left[(y_3-y_1)-(y_3-y_2)\right]+x_3(y_1-y_2)=$$

$$=0$$

so again zero. Do it slowly...!

Comment: It looks like there's something wrong with your algebra moving to the last step. I used both of your formulas for concrete numbers and get different results. The last step doesn't equal the step before it. Where did $x_1$ go?

Comment: @EntangledLoops Perhaps there is a mistake, but you or anyone else substituting numbers and getting something different doesn't say much: perhaps it is **you** who made a mistake...? If you can point at the mistake I will gladly correct it. :)

Comment: Here are 3 points: $(0, 9), (138, 429), (-30, -102)$.
Equation 1 produces: $0(429-(-102)) + 138(-102 - 9) + -30(9-429) = -2718$. Meanwhile, equation 2 produces: $(-30 - 138)(429-9) + 138[(-102-9)-(-102-429)] + -30(9-429) = 0$. I didn't discover this by hand, I wrote a program that uses your formulas verbatim and ran them with real numbers to find this.

Comment: But those three points aren't collinear since the sl0pe between 1st and 2d is $$\frac{429-9}{138}=\frac{420}{138}=\frac{210}{69}=\frac{70}{23}$$wheras the slope between the 2nd and the third is $$\frac{-102-429}{-30-138}=\frac{531}{168}=\frac{177}{56}\neq\frac{70}{29}$$so the first condition isn't fulfilled...

Comment: Ah, I was trying to use this formula to detect if the points were colinear, by checking if the result was 0. I see my mistake now. Instead I guess I can check the determinant.

Answer (score 1):

Elementary row/column operations yield
$$
\left(\matrix{x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\x_3&y_3&1}\right)\sim \left(\matrix{x_1&y_1&1\\x_2-x_1&y_2-y_1&0\\x_3-x_1&y_3-y_1&0}\right)\sim\left(\matrix{0&0&1\\x_2-x_1&y_2-y_1&0\\x_3-x_1&y_3-y_1&0}\right).
$$
So the rank of your matrix is the same as the rank of the latter, which is $1$ plus the rank of the lower left $2\times 2$ block.

Now your three points are collinear, if and only if the two vectors
$$
\vec{P_1P_2}=(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1)\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad \vec{P_1P_3}=(x_3-x_1,y_3-y_1)
$$
are collinear. And this is equivalent to
$$
\det \left(\matrix{x_2-x_1&y_2-y_1\\x_3-x_1&y_3-y_1}\right)=0.
$$
Finally, the latter is equivalent to the fact that the rank of this $2\times 2$ matrix is $0$ or $1$.

So the rank of your initial matrix is $1$ or $2$ when the three points are collinear. And it is $3$ when they are not collinear.